# how to make an ImageView zoomable with or without ScrollView.?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have an `UImageView` in my `IB` and added a map image on that `UImageView`. I want to make that image pinch zoomable.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Map";

   self.mapImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
   [self.mapScrollView addSubview:self.mapImageView];
   [self.mapScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.mapImageView.frame.size.width, self.mapImageView.frame.size.height)];
   [self.mapScrollView setMinimumZoomScale:1.0];
   [self.mapScrollView setMaximumZoomScale:4.0];
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
   return self.mapImageView;
}
```

but this doesn't help, I can see a `UIScrollView` Coming but nothing happen to my image.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you set the delegate of your scroll view?

Comment: I set the delegate just now. now it's zooming but at the same time going back to previos state which doen't solve the purpose of zooming.

Comment: What do you mean by "going back to previous state"?

Comment: while you push one viewcontroller to another that ViewDidLoad called of second view controller but while to pop secod to fist view then ViewDidLoad not called of fistView its ViewwillAppear called so put your Code in to ViewWillAppear

Comment: when i pinch on screen and remove my fingers from screen it just zoom IN and OUT at the same time.

Comment: I am not using any different viewController for zoom.

Comment: getting something like this in my console. Ignoring call to `[UIPanGestureRecognizer setTranslation:inView:]` since gesture recognizer is not active

Answer (score 3):

Add `UIScrollViewDelegate` in your `ViewController.h` file

then add following code to your `ViewController.m` file

No need to add `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` if your using this code

```
    - (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
    {

    UIView* zoomView = [scrollView.delegate viewForZoomingInScrollView:scrollView];

    CGRect zoomViewFrame = zoomView.frame;

    if(zoomViewFrame.size.width < scrollView.bounds.size.width)

    {

    zoomViewFrame.origin.x = (scrollView.bounds.size.width - zoomViewFrame.size.width) / 2.0;

    }

    else

    {
    zoomViewFrame.origin.x = 0.0;
    }

    if(zoomViewFrame.size.height < scrollView.bounds.size.height)

     {      zoomViewFrame.origin.y = (scrollView.bounds.size.height - zoomViewFrame.size.height) / 2.0;

    }
    else

    {
    zoomViewFrame.origin.y = 0.0;
    }
    zoomView.frame = zoomViewFrame;
    }
```

change `viewDidLoad` as follows

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mapScrollView.delegate = self;
    self.mapScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    self.mapScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
    UIImage * myImage= [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]; //add your image here
    [self.mapImageView setImage:myImage];
    [self.mapImageView sizeToFit];
    self.mapScrollView.contentSize = myImage.size;

}
```

Specify the imageView to zoom here

```
- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.mapImageView;
}
```

To avoid the strange behaviour of UIScrollView on zoomimg use this method

```
- (void)view:(UIView*)view setCenter:(CGPoint)centerPoint
{
    CGRect viewFrame = view.frame;
        CGPoint contentOffset = self.mapScrollView.contentOffset;

        CGFloat x = centerPoint.x - viewFrame .size.width / 2.0;
        CGFloat y = centerPoint.y - viewFrame .size.height / 2.0;

    if(x < 0)
    {
        contentOffset.x = -x;
        viewFrame .origin.x = 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        viewFrame .origin.x = x;
    }
    if(y < 0)
    {
        contentOffset.y = -y;
        viewFrame .origin.y = 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        viewFrame .origin.y = y;
    }

    view.frame = viewFrame ;
    self.mapScrollView.contentOffset = contentOffset;
}
```

Then call the above method on viewDidAppear

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    CGPoint centerPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.mapScrollView.bounds),
                                  CGRectGetMidY(self.mapScrollView.bounds));
    [self view:self.mapImageView setCenter:centerPoint];
}
```

have a look at this [link](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2012/07/07/tutorial-all-about-images-part-2-panning-zooming-with-uiscrollview/) if you need more clarification. I learned this technique from that link.

Comment: i am using your code now but nothing happend.

how i have used your code step wise, lemme know if i made any mistakes.

1) added a scrollView in IB and send it to back, set delegate as file's owner
2) remove all my above given code.
3) paste your code after viewDidLoad.
4) Run the code and nothing happend.

Comment: 1. Open .xib and add a UIScrollview 2.add a UIImageView into that UIScrollview 3.create IBOutlet's for UIScrollview and UIImageView and hook it to .xib. 4.add UIScrollViewDelegate in viewController.h like below @interface ScrollxViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate> 5.create properties in viewController.h and synthesize properties in viewController.m 6. change viewDidLoad , scrollViewDidZoom and viewForZoomingInScrollView as above. 7.build and run image will zoom. if you need complete code please let me know i will upload it

Comment: sorry for extreme late reply and i am really thankful to you but still have some problem. wit using ur code it's zooming but not properly, it's zooming horizontally and compressing vertically so nothing is properly in that image. hope u understand the problem here.

Comment: You can refer this link for further clarification. they specified how to center contentview (http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2012/07/07/tutorial-all-about-images-part-2-panning-zooming-with-uiscrollview/)

Comment: @Zac24 Did you resolve this issue? If so please post the solution. I am having a similar problem and it persists despite trying different solutions.

Comment: @George : I have tried your solution and looked at link also but it doesn't seem to work, Still Zoom behaviour is strange only..tht's y earlier i moved to tap to zoom method. But i would like have pinch zoom over tap to zoom.

Answer (score 2):

try with this

```
    //At ViewDidLoad (OR whare you create your mapImageView)
   UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scale:)];
   [pinchRecognizer setDelegate:self];
   [mapImageView addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];

   mapImageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;




   -(void)scale:(id)sender {
       [YourView bringSubviewToFront:[(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view]];

       if([(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
           lastScale = 1.0;  //global float variable.
           return;
       }

       CGFloat scale = 1.0 - (lastScale - [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale]);

       CGAffineTransform currentTransform = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view].transform;
       CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, scale, scale);

       [[(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view] setTransform:newTransform];
   }
```

Comment: app crashed..  

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '<> + <1:1>*0x1f5b0560.marker + <1:-0.5>*0x1f5b5e70.marker + <1:0.5>*0x1f5b5f50.marker + <1:1>*0x1f5bbc40.marker + <1:1>*0x1f5c1760.marker + <1:1>*0x1f5c2a00.marker + <1:0.5>*0x1f5c4150.marker: internal error.  Setting empty vector for variable tempToBeOptimizedToZero.'

Comment: wait. i'll debug and will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

to do it without `scrollView`, Add this Snippet to your class:

```
-(void) addGesturesTo : (UIImageView *) imageView{
    // Register for double-finger dragging to pan the camera.
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer* pinchGestureReconizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self                                                                                                    action: @selector(handlePich:)];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGestureReconizer];
}
- (void) handlePich: (UIPinchGestureRecognizer *) pinchGestureRecognizer{
    CGFloat scale = pinchGestureRecognizer.scale;
    [[pinchGestureRecognizer view]  setTransform:CGAffineTransformScale([pinchGestureRecognizer view].transform, scale, scale)];
    pinchGestureRecognizer.scale = 1.0;
}
```

Now call `addGesturesTo` with `imageView`. As:

```
[self addGesturesTo:imageView];
```

To Do it with ScrollView: Follow These steps:

- add `scrollView` set delegate to self
- Add `imageView` inside `scrolView`
- implement `- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;` in your class and return `imageView`

Comment: to do without scrollView. i will remove scrollView from my viewController and add this code snippet to my class but then where to call this `[self addGesturesTo:imageView];` .

Comment: Where ever youu want. In `viewDidLoad` may be.

Comment: got something like this in console.
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)

Comment: `("<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1f5f5d50 h=--- v=--- H:[UIWindow:0x1f5d43b0(320)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1f5f48d0 h=-&- v=-&- UILayoutContainerView:0x1f5d5620.width == UIWindow:0x1f5d43b0.width>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1f5f34e0 h=-&- v=-&- UINavigationTransitionView:0x1f5d89b0.width == UILayoutContainerView:0x1f5d5620.width>")
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1f5f34e0 h=-&- v=-&- UINavigationTransitionView:0x1f5d89b0.width == UILayoutContainerView:0x1f5d5620.width>`

Comment: Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful. 

this is what m getting in console.

Comment: Do you have autolayout on in your view(check it in you xib, and first section of inspector) if yes try setting it off then check.

Comment: i dont have autolayout, i have autoresize subview and i have mark tick to this.

Comment: Ask another question for this problem then.