# UIScrollView goes crazy when zooming?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I've tried searching for answers for this, but I have no idea what to search for and I'm at wit's end. I've got a UIScrollView that, when zooming, completely flips out and the image glitches everywhere before disappearing entirely. It even manages to, on occasion, temporarily screw up other components that aren't even part of the UIScrollView in which the zooming is happening. I apologize I can't be more technical. I wouldn't even know which part of my code to look at.

I made a video, because I have no technical terminology to describe what's happening here. Any help would be appreciated.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SvhqHI-3_g8

The red is my current background of the UIScrollView. Don't mind that.

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *workingImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *chosenImageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *imageScroller;

-(IBAction)cameraButtonPressed;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.imageScroller.minimumZoomScale = 1.00f;
    self.imageScroller.maximumZoomScale = 15.0f;
    self.imageScroller.contentSize = self.imageScroller.frame.size;
    self.imageScroller.scrollEnabled = YES;
}

-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.chosenImageView;
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *chosenImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [self.chosenImageView setImage:chosenImage];
    [self.imageScroller setContentSize:chosenImage.size];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Some code would be helpful.  What do you have that interacts with the current position/zoom level/scrolling/etc?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. The only method I've implemented is the apple recommended `viewForZoomingInScrollView` which I'll add to the question.

Comment: Not sure if its the cause, but setting the `contentSize` as the size of the view is not exactly good practice.  Try setting the `contentSize` as the size of the image frame when you load it.

Comment: No, that definitely didn't fix it. If it's any help, it ONLY seems to do it when "bouncing". Furthermore, I've found that while the image is completely gone off screen and glitched out, if I try to select a new image it crashes with `Thread 1:EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xdefe)`.

Comment: Have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/16668308/2156974 .This may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this article helps. It seems the missing ScrollViewDidZoom method might be key to maintaining the zoomed view in place. http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content

Comment: Sadly, this didn't solve it. Thank you for your help though. :(

Comment: Have you tried logging the scrollview and image view bounds, content size, methods, etc to see what's happening with the views? Also adding an exception breakpoint can help you to debug at the moment of crashing.

Comment: I had logged the zoom scale itself and was able to watch it go from my minimum to my maximum and stay there, compounding every time as if it had done something to my image. I'm not familiar with how to use exception breakpoints, though, and I haven't found a single tutorial that explains them well.

Comment: @Rob to add an exception breakpoint: go to the breakpoint tab on the left hand side of the screen, click the plus button on the bottom left, select "Add Exception Breakpoint", click "Done"

Comment: @Rob zoom scale is only one part of your puzzle and it won't account for image disappearing. Try logging the bounds, offset, etc to see if it changes or looks correct after zoom is done. You can also follow the article's example in a separate project and see how it works and compare with yours. You'll need to dig deeper.

Comment: So it seems that using the auto layout on the storyboard is what's causing this, but disabling it obviously screws up all my layouts. Is there a way to disable auto layout JUST in the scroll view?